# Get locale-specific drawable from a shared folder in Android

Tags: android, directory, drawable

I have an app that is translated into several languages.  For a certain drawable, all the languages except the default language share the same image.  I know that I can put copies of the non-default drawable in the drawable folder for each language, but that is a waste of space.  Is there a way to just have one drawable for all the languages except the default language.  I'd like to avoid making multiple copies.

Comment: It Depends upon the drawable image . If its a  [TextDrawable](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable/blob/master/screens/screen1-material.png) only then it can be creted at runtime . Otherwise you have pre bundle them .

Comment: Follow this official documwent https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: Put both drawables as default and use selector to choose proper one, depending on localization language.

Comment: I was hoping to just have 2 folders for the two different drawables with the same name, but I guess that is not possible.